# If $f(z)$ is differentiable, show that $|f'(z)|^2=(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a complex valued function which can be represented by $$f(z)=u(x,y) + iv(x,y).$$

If $f(z)$ is differentiable, show that $$\left|f'(z)\right|^2=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2.$$

I am a beginner in complex analysis, so bear with me. In my solution, it is given that
$$f'(z)=u_x + iv_x=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
and things follow from here.
My doubt is, how does the above came into picture. As far as i know, $f(z)$ is a complex valued function with real part as $u(x,y)$ and imaginary part being $v(x,y)$ which are both functions of $x$ and $y$.
How does one calculate the derivative of $f(z)$ by taking partial derivative with respect to $x$ only?

Any help would be appreciated from the community.

Comment: $|z|^2 = z\overline{z}$ would be a place to start.

Comment: Using definition of $f'(z)$: $$ f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(z + h) - f(z)}h,$$ this limit exists, so it does not depend on how $h$ approaches $0$. So certainly you could require $h \in \Bbb R$, and using the form $f = u +\mathrm iv$, you would see this is actually taking partial derivatives $\partial/\partial x$.

Comment: Thanks @xbh , i was just solving in my notebook and it worked. I love this community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, if $z=a+bi$,\begin{align}f'(z)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h\\&=\lim_{h\to0,\ h\in\Bbb R}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h\\&=\lim_{h\to0,\ h\in\Bbb R}\frac{u(a+h,b)-u(a,b)+v(a+h,b)i-v(a,b)i}h\\&=\lim_{h\to0,\ h\in\Bbb R}\frac{u(a+h,b)-u(a,b)}h+\lim_{h\to0,\ h\in\Bbb R}\frac{v(a+h,b)-v(a,b)}hi\\&=u_x(a,b)+v_x(a,b)i.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks sir for writing . I follow your answers regularly on this site. Fanboy moment !!

Comment: On the third and fourth line, $u(a,b)$ and $v(a,b)$ are missing.

Comment: @mrsamy Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.